# How to open in ng2-date-picker on icon click angular?

Tags: angular

I wanted to open the ng2-date-picker on the calendar icon click. I am using below NPM package in angular
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-picker

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved by CSS making calendar icon absolute to the input box and input box background set to transparent with proper z-index to overlap over the icon.